# Time Complexity of Slowsort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I've recently become interested in the time complexity of various sorting algorithms and how to calculate them. However, despite my best efforts, I've been unable to find suitable Big O representation of the slowsort algorithm as given below, implemented in Python:

```py
def _slowsort(a, i, j):
    """in-place sorts the integers in the array
    spanning indexes [i, j].
    """
    # base condition; then no need of sorting if
    #  - there is one element to sort
    #  - when start and end of the array flipped positions
    if i >= j:
        return

    # find the mid index of the array so that the
    # problem could be divided intto sub-problems of
    # smaller spans
    m = (i + j) // 2

    # invoke the slowsort on both the subarrays
    _slowsort(a, i, m)
    _slowsort(a, m + 1, j)

    # once both the subproblems are solved, check if
    # last elements of both subarrays and move the
    # higher among the both to end of the right subarray
    # ensuring that the highest element is placed at the
    # correct relative position
    if a[m] > a[j]:
        a[m], a[j] = a[j], a[m]

    # now that the rightmost element of the array is at
    # the relatively correct position, we invoke Slowsort on all
    # the elements except the last one.
    _slowsort(a, i, j - 1)


def slowsort(a):
    """in-place sorts the array `a` using Slowsort.
    """
    _slowsort(a, 0, len(a) - 1)
```

A basic analysis of algorithm yields T(n) = 2T(n/2) + T(n-1), but I haven't been able to solve recurrence relation after this. Could someone please show how this type of function could be analyzed?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2805500_Pessimal_Algorithms_and_Simplexity_Analysis is the paper where it was introduced, and they prove a lower bound there.

Answer (score 0):

The original paper describing slowsort, ["Pessimal Algorithms and Simplexity Analysis"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/990534.990536), explains that the recursion governing slowsort

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + T(n − 1)
```

can be shown to be bounded like

[image: slow sort bounds]

by assuming the non-recusive defintion of T(n) has the form `c1 * n ^ (c2 * ln n)` and plugging in `C2 = 1/(2 ln 2)` to get the upper bound and `C2 = 1/((2 + e) ln 2)` to get the lower bound for large n, but it doesn't really go into the details.

Comment: I wasn’t able to understand why they assumed the function would be of that form or how they derived the upper and lower bounds. Is there someone who could clarify this?